# how to link user managed identity to azure analysis services

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-managed-identity, azure-analysis-services

I created a user managed identity in a bicep template. Is there a way in azure cli where  i can link this user managed identity created to azure analysis services.
As well as this i need the ,managed identity to have azure analysis services server admin rights. This is a workaround as azure analysis services does not directly support managed
identity.

Comment: hvae you check this article ? not sure if you can do it using az cli: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-server-admins

Comment: you could add the identity to a group and set the group as admin while deploying uing bicep tho

Answer (score 1):

> Currently, Azure CLI **does not support** managing Azure Analysis Services. You can check the GitHub issue **[here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/22973)**.

Alternatively, you can make use of below PowerShell command to add identity to **Server Administrator** role under Azure Analysis Server like this:

```
Set-AzAnalysisServicesServer -Name "aas_server_name" -ResourceGroupName "rg_name" -Administrator "app:<ManagedIdentiyClientId>@<TenantId>"
```

**Response:**

[image]

To confirm that, I checked the same in Portal where identity is added as **Analysis Services Admin** successfully like this:

[image]

If you prefer authenticating with **service principal** instead of managed identity, you can refer this **[SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77825043/automate-creation-of-service-principal-and-adding-admin-rights/77825746#77825746)** that I answered recently.

**Reference:**
[Manage server admins in Azure Analysis Services | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-server-admins)