# Automate creation of service principal and adding admin rights

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli, azure-analysis-services, azure-service-principal

I have created an azure analysis services resource in a bicep template. Due to it not having any support for managed identity's am going to have to use a service principal. Is there a way in azure cli or powershell where i can create a script that creates a service principal and gives it server admin rights on azure analysis services. azure analysis server admin rights is required as i plan do the following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-async-refresh#base-url

Comment: You can create a service principal using MS Graph: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/serviceprincipal?view=graph-rest-1.0. After you've created the principal you can use the Azure APIs to add the correct permissions for this principal.

Comment: you can use `az ad sp` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest. let us know how that goes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of below PowerShell command to create **service principal** in your directory:

```
New-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName "sp_name"
```

To add this service principal to the **Server Administrator** role under Azure Analysis Server, run this command:

```
Set-AzAnalysisServicesServer -Name "aas_name" -ResourceGroupName "rg_name" -Administrator app:appId@tenantId
```

In my case, I used below PowerShell script to create service principal and adding **admin rights** to it under Azure Analysis Server:

```
$sp = New-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName "srianalysisapp1601"

$appId = $sp.AppId
$tenantId = $sp.AppOwnerOrganizationId  

Set-AzAnalysisServicesServer -Name "demoanalysis16" -ResourceGroupName "Sri" -Administrator "app:$appId@$tenantId"
```

**Response:**

[image]

To confirm that, I checked the same in Portal where service principal is added as **Analysis Services Admin** successfully like this:

[image]

**References:**

[New-AzADServicePrincipal (Az.Resources) | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadserviceprincipal?view=azps-11.2.0)

[Manage server admins in Azure Analysis Services | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-server-admins)